# Animation of Image Up and Down / Show and Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and learning it.

Trying to animate an image something shown like in the video (link is below).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TORo-vTtCh5ezkbo9nfHKEqCdqXvh_kQ

Here is code I have tried.

Image animation is working but the image is moving (hiding) to the corner and not upwards.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $.fn.myFunction1();
  $.fn.myFunction2();
   });
   $.fn.myFunction1 = function() {
  $("img").hide(3500);
   }
   $.fn.myFunction2 = function() {
  $("img").show(3500);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button class="btn1">Click Me</button>
 <br>
 <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp2x.gif">
```

Comment: First pointer, don't stick methods on the jQuery namespace unless you have a reason to.  Methods attached to the `jQuery.fn` namespace will be copied to all instantiations of jQuery.  Which given your use case, is not desired.  You already have a namespace created with the document ready.  There's no reason to put them on the jQuery namespace.

Comment: I would recommend not hiding the video on google drive that requires everyone to request access to view.

Comment: I have made videos available publicly

Comment: The link still says access denied, request permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery UI to change the animation effect of the hide/show.

https://jqueryui.com/hide/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("img").hide("blind", {}, 3500);
    $("img").show("blind", {}, 3500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Click Me</button>
<br>
<img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp2x.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a basic slide up and slide down, that can be done with jquery. The problem that you might be experiencing is you are applying the hide/show to the image. Below I apply slideToggle to a div wrapping the img tag. SlideToggle automatically toggles between down and up states.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $("div").slideToggle(3500);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button class="btn1">Click Me</button>
 <br><div>
 <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp2x.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your video, but i assumed, that you want to hide image without scaling. To do so, you should use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) for that kind of animation. Second thing: even if you use above functions, img element will try to keep their aspect ratio, so you need to wrap that image in for example div and then use above functions on that div.

Example below

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $.fn.myFunction1();
  $.fn.myFunction2();
   });
   $.fn.myFunction1 = function() {
  $(".img-wrapper").slideUp(3500);
   }
   $.fn.myFunction2 = function() {
  $(".img-wrapper").slideDown(3500);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Click Me</button>
<br>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp2x.gif">
</div>
```

If you want to scale image during animation, just add some basic CSS to div and img elements (Open preview in fullpage):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $.fn.myFunction1();
  $.fn.myFunction2();
   });
   $.fn.myFunction1 = function() {
  $(".img-wrapper").slideUp(3500);
   }
   $.fn.myFunction2 = function() {
  $(".img-wrapper").slideDown(3500);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Click Me</button>
<br>
<div class="img-wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
  <img  style="max-height:100%;height:auto;width:auto;display:inline-block;"  src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp2x.gif">
</div>
```